# iOS app getting crashed while opening after force closing the app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using https://github.com/vfr/Reader sample for viewing PDF files. If i normally opens the app some times it is getting crash. If i force close the app by double pressing home button, then opening the app will continuously crashing.

```
Mar 11 13:47:43 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
Mar 11 13:47:43 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Incident Identifier: 2E22CC11-149F-4793-A25D-8FB6CC9A4D32
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   51098f3dd34d50a0bad14d75ac0b666e73f8e0eb
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Process:             myApp [1208]
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/DB3B7EED-3388-4F22-A64C-969D0BCCEE39/myApp.app/myApp
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Identifier:          myApp
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Version:             ???
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Date/Time:           2014-03-11 13:47:42.469 +0530
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Report Version:      104
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  0
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Thread 0 Crashed:
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3792d8e6 0x37924000 + 39142
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3792d9a4 0x37924000 + 39332
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3792f76a 0x37924000 + 46954
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 3   libobjc.A.dylib                0x37927fe6 0x37924000 + 16358
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 4   libobjc.A.dylib                0x37927db6 0x37924000 + 15798
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x37929002 0x37924000 + 20482
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 6   CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d097c 0x2d4c9000 + 31100
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 7   Foundation                     0x2deb885c 0x2deb2000 + 26716
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 8   UIKit                          0x2fd79b58 0x2fd04000 + 482136
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 9   GraphicsServices               0x321b070a 0x321a7000 + 38666
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 10  GraphicsServices               0x321b02f2 0x321a7000 + 37618
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 11  CoreFoundation                 0x2d5679dc 0x2d4c9000 + 649692
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 12  CoreFoundation                 0x2d567976 0x2d4c9000 + 649590
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 13  CoreFoundation                 0x2d56614a 0x2d4c9000 + 643402
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 14  CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d0c22 0x2d4c9000 + 31778
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 15  CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d0a06 0x2d4c9000 + 31238
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 16  UIKit                          0x2fd78dd4 0x2fd04000 + 478676
Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: 17  UIKit
```

Anyone tell me that how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
```

See the above line.. Go to the path shown above & clear it.. Let me know if still issue remains.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay.how to access the above path and how to delete?

Comment: @surfer Actually you cannot simply delete those files as it will throw Cocoa error 513. Better to clear crash logs from Xcode organizer. You can use this method while testing with simulator though..:)

Comment: @surfer.. Actually this solution is just for the crash happening when you reopen the app.. Actually first time the app is crashing due to bad access.. see it here "Mar 11 13:47:44 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)" .. now you have to use breakpoints & check where is it happening. narrow down the issue & let us know if you get stuck somewhere.. :)

Comment: app getting crashed only if i force close the app and reopen only.. other than this working fine... so i unable to find the issues.. please help to fix this issue.

Comment: @surfer.. I've downloaded the reader & tried the same thing. Works fine for me.. Are you sure you have not changed anything in the code?

Comment: @surfer What do you mean by "i have used only necessory views"

Comment: i didnt used the whole app, just pdf views source only

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could de-symbolise the error, but judging by the first 2 lines your device is running out of space?

```
Mar 11 13:47:43 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
Mar 11 13:47:43 eV-iPhone-4-Black ReportCrash[1210] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
```

**UPDATE:**

- Connect your device to your machine.
- In Xcode open up the Organizer window
- Select the Devices icon at the top
- From the Library option on the left select Device Logs
- There should be a large list of crash logs, remove those
- Run your app again and the log should now appear in the list
- Click Re-Symbolicate if it hasn't already done so automatically